# How to relate multiplicity function, entropy and partition function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

In different textbooks about [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics), the authors would expound the theory in different ways. I am very confused and aghast for that, you know you will meet some concepts for different situations again and again.

> $\textbf{So what's framework or outline to learn statistical mechanics logically?}$

I guess the following three concepts are the most important things to link the whole statistical mechanics. (primarily following the book written by Kittle)

$$\textbf{multiplicity function $(\Omega)$} \quad ; \quad \textbf{entropy} (S= k\ln \Omega) \quad;\quad \textbf{partition function} (Z) $$

But I cannot build physically a reasonable relation between them.Someone tells me the first thing you need to do is to calculate the partition function (encode everything about your system), playing the same role as Lagrangian in classical mechanics, of your system of interest. But in Kittle's book seems the multiplicity function and hence the entropy (by Boltzmann entropy formula) also encode everything about the whole system.

> $\textbf{So what's the relations between these concepts?}$

Comment: I am a bit lost as to what you are asking for here. Take $\Omega$ and $ S$. You state the definition of entropy, which incorporates  $\Omega$ and then ask what the relationship between them is, well you have written down what   the relationship actually **is**.  Are you asking for an explanation of how we arrive at multiplicities,  or what $k$ represents, or why we take the natural  log of $\Omega$ instead of $\Omega$  itself.  I would be more than happy to attempt an answer, but I don't know what the question you are asking is :)

Comment: In kittle's book, the authors seem to want to pave a way from the multiplicity function (encode everything about your system but one cannot calculate it in general) to entropy and then to partition function. Here the multiplicity function and entropy seems to have a relation in terms of the famous Boltzmann formula. But I wonder based on what we can define this formula? I mean what's the difference between calculating the entropy and the multiplicity function? And how can I relate both concepts to partition function for different ensembles?

Comment: I have modified my question, is that clear now?

Comment: Thanks Jack, your line **But I wonder based on what we can define this formula? I mean what's the difference between calculating the entropy and the multiplicity function** is the same question as Schroeder asks the reader in his book, and he does say, (I think) something to the effect, "just treat them the same." But I will need to check. Thanks